# Como posicionar corretamente um pedaço da View criado em java?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Após carregar minha `View`, se o usuário clique no botão então aparece um menu na frente como mostra na imagem:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

A camada mais superior deste menu é um `FrameLayout`, gostaria de deixa-lo com `Gravity` `RIGHT` e `BOTTOM`, mas não sei passar essas características por [java](/questions/tagged/java)

estou fazendo desta forma:

---

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.RIGHT);
    frame_dados.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

---

Quero configura-lo em desta forma:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
```

Comment: Isso, deixa-lo bottom | Right, essa é minha dúvida, o resto arrumo depois

Comment: Seu linear_dados é um LinearLayout?

Comment: É um frame, tinha escrito errado

Comment: Boa, funcionou aqui!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa definição do `FrameLayout` no XML, exemplo:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
```

É equivalente a esta programaticamente:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lparams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html).